# Calculating directional derivative- theoretical question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{n}} (0,0)$ of the following function:
$$
f(x,y)= \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \, @(x,y)\neq (0,0)
$$
$$
f(0,0)=0
$$

My calculation yielded the following limit:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2}{h \left| h \right|} n_1 n_2
$$
where $(n_1,n_2)$ is my (normalized) direction.

Can I deduce that my directional derivative is $n_1 n_2$ ? What can I do with the absolute value in the denominator and what is its meaning? Is it true that in the case of directional derivatives , the limit is actually $h\to 0^+$ ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\cap n}(0,0)$? I'm confused about the $\cap$ in the denominator.

Comment: Most sources define the directional derivative with $h \to 0$ (like for the usual partial derivatives). With $h \to 0^+$, one gets the *one-sided* directional derivative instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true that in the case of directional derivatives , the limit is actually $h\to 0^+$ ?

No. If you have a function on a closed domain, then sometimes you define the derivative at the boundary with an onesided limit. But you have to be very careful how to interpret this.
But in your case $(0,0)$ is no boundary point. Therefore you have to consider the usual limit $t\to 0$, where $t$ can be positive or negative.

That is why your limit doesn't exists if $n_1\neq 0$ and $n_2\neq 0$, because you get for the restriction $t>0$ and $t<0$ different results.

This is not very suprising, since you can consider you function on the diagonal set $f(x,x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}|x|$ which is obiously not differentiable as a function in $x$ at $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  !!